# Help using Horner's rule and hash functions in Java?

Tags: java, hashtable

I am trying to use Horner's rule to convert words to integers.  I understand how it works and how if the word is long, it may cause an overflow.  My ultimate goal is to use the converted integer in a hash function h(x)=x mod tableSize.  My book suggests, because of the overflow, you could "apply the mod operator after computing each parenthesized expression in Horner's rule."  I don't exactly understand what they mean by this.  Say the expression looks like this:

((14*32+15)*32+20)*32+5

Do I take the mod tableSize after each parenthesized expression and add them together?  What would it look like with this hash function and this example of Horner's rule?

Answer (score 5):

The book is saying that you should take advantage of these mathematical equivalences:

```
(a * b) mod m = ((a mod m) * (b mod m)) mod m
(a + b) mod m = ((a mod m) + (b mod m)) mod m
```

Thus,

```
h = (((x*c) + y)*c + z) mod m
```

Is equivalent to

```
        _   _   _  _
h = (((x*c) + y)*c + z)
```

Where

```
  _
a * b = ((a mod m) * (b mod m)) mod m
  _
a + b = ((a mod m) + (b mod m)) mod m
```

Essentially, for each basic addition and basic subtraction, you replace it with an "advanced" version that `mod` the operands, and `mod` the results. Since operands to the basic multiplication are now in the range of `0..m-1`, the biggest number you'll get is `(m-1)^2`, which can alleviate overflow if `m` is small enough.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia:modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation)
- [Wikipedia:modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

  - `-1 mod 2 = 1` mathematically, but `-1 % 2` in Java is `-1`.

---

By the way, it should be pointed out that 32 is a terrible choice of multiplier for hash functions of this class (since it's not a prime), especially for computing (since it's a power of 2). Much better is 31, because:

- It's prime (mathematically important!)
- It's one less than a power of two, so it can be optimized to a cheaper shift and subtract

  - `31 * i == (i << 5) - i`

Answer (score 2):

They mean replace the result of a parenthesized expression with that result mod tableSize:

```
((((14*32+15)%tableSize)*32+20)%tableSize)*32+5
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to understand this using the Java code. We should apply the modulo operator at each step in the calculation inside the loop:

```
public static int hashCode(String key) {
    int hashVal = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < key.length(); j++) {
        // For small letters.
        int letter = key.charAt(j) - 96; 
        hashVal = (hashVal * 32 + letter) % arraySize; // mod
    }
    return hashVal;
}
```